# c++ are two strings the same?

Tags: c++, string, compare

I'm trying to make a simple software asked to enter a key.

I use `fstream` to open `txt` file which contains a list of numbers. I put in `string array import_n`, then I defined a string, say `user_input`. I use `getline(cin, user_input)` to get the user input. `if user_input == import_n`, means that user entered a correct number, and that the comparison was successful.

This works fine. The problem is, when the program asks the user to enter the number and I press enter key it continues like I entered a correct number. Is there a way to deal with that?

**Note:**

I tried

```
if (cin.get() == '\n') {continue;}
```

but the problem with that is

1: When the user enters the number and I press enter it's repeated again even if the number is correct

2:

```
if(cin.get() == '\n'){cout <<"you press enter";}
else getline(cin, user_input);
```

the problem here is that it skips the first number of `user_input`

**The code:**

```
string user_input  = "";
string g;
string il_[ar_n +1];
string wa[na];
string w1 ="array";
string w2 ="_";
for (int n = 1, i = 0; i < na; i++, n++)
{
stringstream c;
c << n;
 wa[i]  = c.str();
}
string w4 =".txt";
string w5 ;

    cout << "enter number : " ;
    getline(cin, g);
            //cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, user_input );

for (int ifo =0 ; ifo< na ; ifo++)  // na -1
{
 w5 = w1 + w2 + wa[ifo] + w4;
ifstream inp(w5);
  if (!inp)
  {
   continue;
  }

int i = 0;
    while (!inp.eof())
    {
        getline(inp, il_[i]);
        i++;
    }
    i = i-1;


    int ic =0 ;
    while (ic < i+1)
    {
      if (user_input == il_[ic])
       {
        f = true;
        break ;
       }
    else
        ic++;
    }
if (f)
{
        inp.close();
    return true;
}

inp.close();

}//end for loop

cout <<"\ninvalid number!";


return false;
```

}

Comment: Could please put a bit more efforts in formatting your explanation and code correctly.

Comment: What else is in the `for` loop?  At the moment, it doesn't seem to have an end brace, so there could be anything in the code.  Please make the code into an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) — doing so allows us to help better than what you've currently shown.

Comment: am sorry, that the code not follow MCVE, it's m first time ask question here. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `cin.get()`, you consume the first character from `cin`. You will need to store it somewhere and attach it to the result of `getline`.

Comment: thanks sir, i keep cin.get();  then add it at first of the user_input, and it work, 
c = cin.get();
  if(c == '\n')
  {
         cout <<"\nno entry!\n";
  break;
  }
  else
  getline(cin, user_input);
  user_input= c +user_input;